# When I turn O_NONBLOCK on i get "0" and "I/O error"

Tags: c, linux, tcp, redhat

When I turn on `O_NONBLOCK` my connection len returns `0` and my errno returns `EIO`. I am  expecting len to be `-1` and errno to be  `EAGAIN`. Based on what I am getting I can assume there is a problem with the initial connection. What I don't understand is why I am getting it. If I comment out where I turn on `O_NONBLOCK` I do not have this issue at all. Am I missing something in regards to turning on `O_NONBLCOK`?

**MY CODE (MAIN())**

```
long len;

//Var for O_NONBLOCKING
int flags;

printf("R thread - starting\n");

MainTcpipIndex = TcpipIndex = 0;
while ( fMainShutdown == FALSE )
  {

  s_MuxWait(5000, "", &hevTcpipBuffAvail[MainTcpipIndex], 0);
  if ( hevTcpipBuffAvail[MainTcpipIndex] == 0)
     continue;

  len = s_recv( lSocket, TcpipRecord[MainTcpipIndex].TcpipBuffer,
              sizeof(TcpipRecord[MainTcpipIndex].TcpipBuffer));

    //initialize flags var      
  flags = fcntl(lSocket, F_GETFL, 0);

  //turns on O_NONBLOCKING
  fcntl(lSocket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

  if (len == -1  ||  len == 0 && errno != EAGAIN)  //0 = connection broken by host
     {
         ReceiveError = errno;
         hevReceiveError = 1;
         printf("R_main - set hevReceiveError ON\n");
         pthread_exit(NULL);
     }
 //catches O_NONBLOCK
 if (len == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
     {
         LogMessage(&LogStruct, INFO, LOGQUEUE + LOGSCREEN, "Caught the
                     O_NONBLOCKING\n");
         len = 0;
         continue;
     }

  // Record Length
  TcpipRecord[MainTcpipIndex].ulTcpipBufLen = len;

  // Tell T Thread we have a message
  hevTcpipBuffUsed[MainTcpipIndex] = 1;
  hevTcpipBuffAvail[MainTcpipIndex] = 0;

  // Maintain Index
  if ( ++MainTcpipIndex >= MAX_TCPIP_BUFFS )
     MainTcpipIndex = 0;

  }//end while
```

**EDIT**

Maybe I did not make this clear the first time, I understand that errno and len has to do with `s_recv`
My issue is that I am getting undesired results when I turn on O_NONBLOCK; `s_recv`'s errno is EIO and its
len is 0. If I turn turn off `O_NONBLOCK` then all of my issues go away; len is 1 or more and errno does not
need to be checked.

Below is a example of th scenarios I expect:

In the first bad scenario `s_recv`'s Len is 0 or -1, errno is not EAGAIN, and the connection is reset.

In the second bad sceanrio `s_recv`'s Len is -1 and errno is EAGAIN. This is the exepected scenario for when
O_NONBLOCK is turned on based off the man pages.

In the good sceanrio `s_recv`'s len is more than 1 and there is no need to check errno.

Comment: Why do you set `O_NONBLOCK` *after* reading? And in case of non-blocking sockets its better to use `select`/`poll`.

Comment: why do you fcntl in a loop and after s_recv? And why do you believe fcntl can not alter the errno after s_recv ?

Comment: Eddy_EM: I initially set O_NONBLOCK after reading for debugging purposes. I plan to move everything to a function that is doing the initial connection.

Comment: oleg_g: This was a quick implementation to do some quick debugging. I understand your point, it should be set outside the `while` loop. I am sure I understand your second question...I am not trying to alter errno, just checking it.

Comment: Note that a call to recv returning 0 does not set errno. It is not an error - it means the peer has gracefully closed the connection. You're probably reading a transient errno value that is not meaningful. Also the `//catches O_NONBLOCK` line is wrong, as the first `if` condition is wrong and will catch it instead

Comment: "When I turn on O_NONBLOCK my connection len returns 0 and my errno returns EIO." 1. When recv() returns zero, the peer has closed the connection. 2. The value of errno is irrelevant unless -1 was returned. Read the 'man' page. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to `O_NONBLOCK` is not relevant before the *next* read.

So, You must check `len` and `errno` *before* you call `fcntl`. And you must check the return value of `fcntl` of course, because it might fail as well.

To summarize, `len == 0` and `errno == EIO` has nothing to do with the change to `O_NONBLOCK`, but with the `s_recv` before.

Additionally, be aware that your

```
if (len == -1 || len == 0 && errno != EAGAIN)
```

is the same as

```
if (len == -1 || (len == 0 && errno != EAGAIN) )
```

which is not meaningful, because if the return value is *not* `-1`, errno must be ignored. If the return value is `0`, then the peer has closed the connection.

**Update**:

I've built a simple echo client

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd == -1)
    error("socket");

he = gethostbyname("localhost");
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)he->h_addr)->s_addr;
addr.sin_port = htons(7); /* echo */
if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    error("connect");

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
    n = strlen(buf);
    printf("fgets=%d, %s", n, buf);
    if (send(fd, buf, n, 0) == -1)
        error("send");

    n = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (n == -1)
        error("recv");

    printf("recv=%d, %s", n, buf);

    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    printf("flags=%d\n", flags);
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
        error("fcntl");
}
```

and after setting `O_NONBLOCK`, I receive

> errno=11
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable

If I move `fcntl(O_NONBLOCK)` before the loop, everything works fine.

So, it seems not advisable to fiddle with non blocking after reading or writing to the socket.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain this correctly the first time, I understand that len and errno has to do with the `s_recv`. My issue is that when I turn on `O_NONBLOCK` my `s_recv` is giving me non-desired results; len is 0 and errno is EIO. If I comment out the code turning on `O_NONBLOCK` everything works as normal. I.E.: In the first good scenario my `s_recv` len is 1 or more and there is no need to check errno. In the second good scenario my `s_recv` len is -1 (based on O_NONBLOCK)In a bad scenario if the connection is broke or something else happens len is

Comment: @WorkerBee If `len == 0`, you must ignore `errno`, because `errno` is set only when `len == -1`. If you get `len == 0`, then this means EOF. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Olaf dietsche - Ok, should `s_recv`'s len return 0 if `O_NONBLOCK` is on? The reason I am asking is if I comment out the spot where I turn `O_NONBLCOK` on I don't get any issues.

Comment: @WorkerBee This should be unrelated, but I have no experience setting `O_NONBLOCK` after `read`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line:

```
if (len == -1  ||  len == 0 && errno != EAGAIN)
```

This is equivalent to

```
if (len == -1  ||  (len == 0 && errno != EAGAIN))
```

so if there's no data available (`len == -1`) you won't check `errno` and will just unconditionally flag an error and exit.  In addition, when there's an EOF (`len == 0`), errno won't be set, so checking it will give whatever happened to be there from previous calls.

You probably want:

```
if ((len < 0 && errnor != EGAIN) || len == 0) {
    ReceiveError = (len < 0) ? errno : 0;
```

Also, if there's an error from fcntl, that will clobber errno (though I expect that isn't happening -- the only failure you might see with GETFL/SETFL is EBADF.)  You probably want to do the fcntl calls BEFORE the recv call.